# Magento 2.4.3 - Translation Issue

Tags: stock, localisation, magento2.4.3

I'm trying to translate "Availability %1" to "På lager: %1" and this happens.

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Where and how do you put your translation, and where is the original translation?

Comment: For this i used PHPAdmin and translation table

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna for which country you are translating this?

Comment: @ArunSharma Norwegian

Answer (score 0):

"Only x left threshold was set to 0 so that is why %1 was not working. When I did set a threshold it worked.